# Is it OK to use pixel dimensions when designing a website?

Tags: language-agnostic

I have started learning some web development lately and have noticed lot's of sites just use Pixel dimension to specify sizes of thins as well as the overall size of the body.

This seems counter intuitive to me (maybe because I am used to programing for Android)
But this could make the website a pain to view on lower res screens and less useful on higher end screens.

Is this really the way things are done? Does this not cause to much problems?

Thanks.

EDIT: how would one go about implementing a less fixed size site?

Comment: Typically, pages have pixel widths they normally support; it's a calculated risk. You expect most of the people of your site to be able to view your site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are pros and cons to doing things like this.

Pros: It allows you to have full control over where everything is placed as sometimes with relative sizing things will move in unexpected ways.

Cons: Well you mentioned them! Different size screens will give the site a different look.

But overall to some people it is more important that everything remains in the right place than that everything looks great on all screen sizes. Ultimately it depends on the preference of the designer. Also remember that uses on higher resolution screens can zoom in and those on lower resolutions can zoom out!

Answer (score 1):

Peaces and pears.

Each to their own, so long as they are consistant and know what they are doing that is all that matters.

I have recently starting using grid templating which uses pixel dimensions for containers and I really enjoy it. Considering that `960.gs` (960px) is an accepted size width for a website, if you know that you do not want to develop a fluid template, then why not use fixed width pixels.

If I am going to have a mobile version of my phone, then I serve the mobile version not my 960px website, and in any case, most phones intuitively display websites anyway. (At least the latest phones, obviously not the old Nokia 8210's ;).